# Whatever I draw in 2d animation, it will turn on the guides and draw a circle

Tags: 2d

[image]

This is blender v2.91.2 for mac. I'm a beginner and stuck in this for two days. I want to draw something and fill something and suddenly I cant draw.

It just draw different circles. I  turn off the guides, but it doesn't work. Whatever I draw, the guides will turn on and all I can do is draw a circle.

Comment: anybodys help?please

Comment: anyone please.I'm still online

Comment: anydude?anydude?i'm still here

Comment: anyone？I upload a new blender ,but the problem sill have

Comment: Are you trying to do  something like this?
https://youtu.be/Or1HtAG9M-s

Comment: thank you,but he didn't met my problem,seems like.